# Smack message xml in <body> error 503

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I'm sending packet using smack library and I'm getting error 503 I suppose it could be caused by xml in body brackets but I'm not sure. I tried to make my own PacketExtension not body but it doesn't help. Here is message which I'm getting back from server. Message is received but another client and well parsed but I'm wondering why there is error.

```
<message id="Ly3iT-34" to="yyyyyy" from="xxxxxx" type="error"><body>&lt;xxxxx type=&quot;road_status_choose&quot;&gt;
    &lt;version&gt;1.1&lt;/version&gt;
   &lt;msg_id&gt;137482497930710041374824168527&lt;/msg_id&gt;
    &lt;timestamp&gt;1374824979307&lt;/timestamp&gt;
  &lt;road_status_previous_path class=&quot;java.util.ArrayList&quot;&gt;
     &lt;road_status&gt;
        &lt;road_status_name&gt;Postój&lt;/road_status_name&gt;
      &lt;road_status_id&gt;2&lt;/road_status_id&gt;
    &lt;/road_status&gt;
 &lt;/road_status_previous_path&gt;
   &lt;status_list_id&gt;1&lt;/status_list_id&gt;
  &lt;road_status_path class=&quot;java.util.ArrayList&quot;&gt;
   &lt;road_status&gt;
    &lt;road_status_name&gt;Jazda&lt;/road_status_name&gt;
       &lt;road_status_id&gt;1&lt;/road_status_id&gt;
    &lt;/road_status&gt;
   &lt;road_status&gt;
        &lt;road_status_name&gt;Z ładunkiem&lt;/road_status_name&gt;
         &lt;road_status_id&gt;7&lt;/road_status_id&gt;
      &lt;road_status_parent_id&gt;1&lt;/road_status_parent_id&gt;
     &lt;/road_status&gt;
  &lt;/road_status_path&gt;
   &lt;status_list_type&gt;0&lt;/status_list_type&gt;
 &lt;/infis_message&gt;</body><error code="503" type="CANCEL"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error><properties xmlns="http://www.jivesoftware.com/xmlns/xmpp/properties"><property><name>RECEIVED</name><value type="boolean">true</value></property></properties></message>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error code 503 means The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7743884/1276374

Comment: but I got this error with every message is it possible ?

Comment: when you login, can you printout your login status?

Comment: Supports Service Discovery info (http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info)
 Supports Service Discovery items list (http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items)
 Supports file transfers via SOCKS5 Bytestreams (http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams)
 Supports execution of Ad-Hoc commands (http://jabber.org/protocol/commands)
 Supports multi-user chat (http://jabber.org/protocol/muc)
 Can report information about the last activity of the user (jabber:iq:last)
 Can send and receive ping requests (urn:xmpp:ping)
 Supports XHTML formatting of chat messages (http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im)

Comment: I think it can be something with <property><name>RECEIVED ...

Comment: Hey found any solution? i facing the same issue with smack 4.2